# how to write usql query to output to multiple files

Tags: azure-data-lake, data-partitioning

i want to group data set based on unique values in column and save them  to multiple file.

My problem is same as which is already described here at link:
[U-SQL Output in Azure Data Lake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636855/u-sql-output-in-azure-data-lake/42676271#42676271)

As i am new to USQL language , i am unable to implement the second step from answer. I am unable to figure out how to write usql query to run generated usql script from the first part of answer

Comment: You can't write U-SQL that runs other U-SQL, ie dynamic U-SQL is not supported.  What you do is 1) open the generated script and run it yourself or 2) run it via Data Factory 3) run it via Powershell etc

Answer (score 1):

If the number of groups is known in advance, you could write a USQL stored [procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt771906.aspx) that would take as parameter 1) the value of the group  2) the name of the file.

In the pseudo-code below, the name of the final file is driven by the underlying value of the group. The data to be split is sourced from a USQL table (referred in the pseudo-code as ).

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS splitByGroups;
CREATE PROCEDURE splitByGroups(@groupValue string, @file_name_prefix string = "extract")
AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @OUTPUT string = "/output/" + file_name_prefix + "_"+ @groupValue + ".csv";

      OUTPUT (
        SELECT *
        FROM <MyTable>
        WHERE <MyGroup> == @groupValue
      )
      TO @OUTPUT
      USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader : true);
END;
```

You would then execute the stored procedure as many times as you have groups:

```
splitByGroups("group1", DEFAULT); 
splitByGroups("group1", DEFAULT);
```

Alternatively, if you wish to analyse the multiple files offline, I would download the full file and use the shell (PowerShell or Linux Shell) to split the file.