# I want to output multiple files using U-SQL according to the number of rows

Tags: output, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I want to output a single table into multiple files in U-SQL according to the number of rows.

> If my table is having 500 rows, then I have to generate 5 files or 100 rows in each file.

Followed the post, [U-SQL Output in Azure Data Lake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636855/u-sql-output-in-azure-data-lake/45274215)

Comment: I'd be happy to help. This may be what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636855/u-sql-output-in-azure-data-lake/42676271#42676271

Comment: But in the post they haven't given the script for "/output/genscript.usql" .

Comment: The script you see in the post generates that script. You will then have to download it and run it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate separate files based on number of rows, you would have to add a `ROW_NUMBER()` to each row. Then generate a script (for example with U-SQL, see [U-SQL Output in Azure Data Lake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636855/u-sql-output-in-azure-data-lake/45274215) as an example) that creates an output statement for each of the row regions. Note the script generation file probably uses an inner join with a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @data` to generate the right number of `OUTPUT` statements. Also you want the first statement in the generated script to be the one that adds the `ROW_NUMBER()` to the rowset that you then output.

Once you generated the script that does that, you can then download it and submit it.

Comment: wouldnt the more "correct" approach be to create Jobs at the same unit of work as 1 record ? this way there's no monkeying with row_number function etc?