# How to Add additional Column to a file in U-SQL

Tags: u-sql

I have need to add additional Columns to each file under a folder.

I am getting error

E_CSC_USER_DATAPARTITIONEDOUTPUTNOTSUPPORTED: Data partitioned output is not supported.

```
@q =
    EXTRACT OrderID int,
        OrderDate DateTime?,
        CustomerName string,
        PhoneNumber string,
        DeliveryAddressLine1 string,
        DeliveryAddressLine2 string,
        CityName string,
        StockItemID int?,
        Quantity int?,
        UnitPrice float?,
        filename string,
        extension string
    FROM "/Orders/{filename}.{extension}"
    USING Extractors.Tsv(skipFirstNRows:1);



OUTPUT @q TO "/Orders/Processed/{filename}.{extension}"
USING Outputters.Csv(outputHeader:true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently dynamic partitioned output (aka using {} wildcards in output paths) is currently in preview. If you're interested, please email usql at Microsoft dot com with more information about your scenario to see if the preview would work for you.

Otherwise, you could script your output via U-SQL or Powershell.  Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636855/u-sql-output-in-azure-data-lake/42676271#42676271).